# Question deleted, not moved

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I was writing this good subjective question for 30-60 minutes, and I asked it in Stackoverflow, but people thought it was too subjective and it got deleted.

I wonder if I can get the original source of that code back, or it it gone forever.

The reason why I ask this is that I want to ask it in a Stack Exchange forum, where it belongs, but I am not sure if it was moved or deleted.

This is the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340550/which-technologies-are-popular-in-java-at-the-moment.

Comment: It was deleted, but luckily, 10k+ users can see deleted posts. I put the contents here: http://pastebin.com/W4mq1pXp

Comment: "at the moment" instant recipe for 'closed, too localized' on every single site.

Answer (score 11):

It does not belong in any Stack Exchange site. Some Stack Overflow users might suggest Programmers, but there it would be closed as not constructive.

When the FAQ mentions "software tools commonly used by programmers", it is not removing the requirement of specific, answerable questions.

> [**What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)
>
> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an *entire book* that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

Comment: I do not find an example at the moment, but I am pretty sure I have seems dozen of questions with the same "level of practicality". It is just sad I can not ask this question anywhere. :(

Comment: I found some examples : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426/what-is-a-good-windows-hex-editor-viewer , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270121/best-latex-editor-for-windows , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141073/whats-the-best-wysiwyg-editor-for-use-with-jquery , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464/what-is-the-worst-interview-question etc etc

Answer (score 3):

Your question is below.

---

### Which technologies are popular in Java at the moment?

As reading FAQ, about which questions can I ask here, I found this point:

***software tools commonly used by programmers**

I wanted to take this a step further, so not to talk about software, but I wanna ask about programming Technologies. Specifically in Java.

At the moment for web developing I know that using Spring+Hibernate is good, eh.
But what other options are out there, add some pros and cons for each is possible.

Furthermore, web developing is of course more popular, but also share some technologies of Java server-client developing.

So this question certainly does not have only one correct answer, but each answer will definitely contribute to this topic.